# Onsen UI transition Effect delay

Tags: angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

im developing my first app with onsen ui and angular js. I have a dude. When i navigate between differents links from my lateral menu the app show the last page before load the new page. I dont know how explain very well the problem.
The last page displayed is stuck before loading the new page.

If you want some code just tell me.

To see the problem on live my app is here: https://build.phonegap.com/apps/1282748/share

Thanks a lot

Comment: It would be better if you post some code, especially if you recreate the problem in Codepen or something similar.

Comment: Hi Fran, is very difficult show the problem with the code. You can try my app in this link: http://recorramisiones.com.ar/rutadelaselva/app2/ there can see the problem too. Thanks!

Comment: I think it is just slow because your pages are a bit heavy. When you visit a link for the first time and it is stored in cache, the second time looks better. Maybe you can try using `<ons-template>` so your templates are preloaded :/

Comment: Thanks @FranDios i wil try with ons-template.

Comment: Hola @FranDios i try with ons-template but the problem persist... another idea? Thanks